# crystal reports missing columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports

OK, first question here so go easy!
Let's start with some quick background - I have been working with Crystal almost daily for the past 15 years to so, so I like to think I am not too much of a dummy.

Today, I have stumbled across a problem I have never seen.

My source data is from SQL Server 2012 Standard.
I have created a view, nothing too complicated.  It grabs PartNo and Description from an Inventory Main table.  Then a few other columns from other related tables so I can see the data neatly in a single view, so stuff like carton qty (how many units go into 1 carton), height, length, depth.

Now, bear in mind I have done these kinds of views so many times in the past I couldn't even count.
Now, in Crystal Reports 2013, I connect to SQL via OLE using sa credentials, find my view. Pop over to the "Links" tab in the Database Expert, and my columns created from the related tables are not listed!  Only PartNo and Description are visible.

I have scratching my head over this for the past few hours & the only thing I can put it down to is some kind of weird Microsoft update.

My SQL view results:
SQL view
[image]

What I see in Crystal
Database Expert, Links

[image]

Comment: What are the data type of the columns that are missing? You might be seeing this behavior because of a mismatch with the data type in the interface between SQL and Crystal.  You may also have a caching issue within your Crystal Report Settings.  Can you share the "Create" SQL statement for your View and the underlying table?

Comment: Also, have you installed any Crystal Report "patches"? -- those are a sure way to invite peculiar behavior into your reports functionality.

Comment: Also, trying using the SQL native client instead of the OleDb Provider... OK that's it.

Comment: can you post your view in full t-sql mode

Comment: the other way to test this is instead of a view or table just add a command and select * from yourview

Comment: Glenn - The data type of the missing cols are all varchar.  Yes, I may have installed some Crystal patches - can't be 100% sure.
I will give the SQL native client a go - nice tip.

Comment: maSTA - will try Glenn's tip of using SQL native client.
Failing that, will try doing a command with the full SELECT statement I need.
Thanks for the tips fellas.  Still learning after all these years!

Comment: OK - so did a quick test & it seems that using a command with a SELECT statement has done the trick!
It's a workaround & doesn't really get to the root of the issue, but it'll do & it works.

Comment: EDIT:  So I found found the underlying cause if this issue.  The datatype in SQL is varchar(max).  Seems CR 2013 doesn't like it, so I modded my view to CONVERT(varchar(254), MyTable.MyCol) and bingo - all good!

Comment: yup... basically you need to define the data type in the view... same with dates. does not like to be converted otherwise will treat it as a string

Answer (score 0):

> the other way to test this is instead of a view or table just add a
>   command and select * from yourview

the only downside i think would be using sql expression from a command connection.

another option is to

> To define the data type in the view... same with dates. does not like
>   to be converted otherwise will treat it as a string

Comment: I know this is a really old question but I was having the same issue and found the solution - for me anyway.
In my source view that had missing cols when using Crystal, I changed the missing columns (which in my case were varchar(max))   to CAST(MyMissingCols to varchar(256)).
Then I removed and re-added my view & the columns appeared.